# Right way to set constraint on function arguments

Tags: haskell

I have some function. And I want to restrict types that can be passed to this function. Let's say only types that are cacheable. I can enumerate such types with a type family like:

```hs
type family Cacheable a::Bool where
  Cacheable X = 'True
  Cacheable _ = 'False
```

And add such a constraint to my function:

```hs
myFunc :: forall a. (Cacheable a ~ 'True) => ....
```

but this constraint is little bit redundant: I can remove it from the function's signature, and nothing changes. Nothing forces it to be in the signature.

Another approach is to create some typeclass whose usage in the body of `myFunc` will force me to add this constraint to `myFunc`'s signature:

```hs
class Cacheable a
  ensureCacheable :: ()
  ensureCacheable = ()

instance Cacheable X

myFunc :: forall a. (Cacheable a) => ...
myFunc =
  let _ = ensureCacheable @a
  in ...
```

but it looks little bit funny.

What is the right/canonical way to do it in Haskell?

Let's suppose that `Cacheable` cannot have any reasoning methods. Think about it like about some classifier. Another name is `IsQuery` (vs `IsCommand`) and queries are cacheable, commands - no.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with adding a constraint as you did, even if the constraint is redundant (not exploited in the body of the function). As long as you do have a reason for the restriction (e.g. you plan to use the constraint in a future version and you don't want to break old code), that looks fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of discussion, let's pick a single terminology:

```
type family CacheableTF a :: Bool where
  CacheableTF X = 'True
  CacheableTF _ = 'False

class CacheableC a
instance CacheableC X
```

What's the difference between these? Two aspects:

- `CacheableTF a` expresses in *classical logic* the fact that `a` is a cacheable type. It's just a boolean after all. Thus you can arbitrarily stack negations on top of this. `(Cacheable a ~ 'False) => ....` is a constraint just as valid as the `'True` version.
  By contrast, `CacheableC a` is constructive, it's a proposition, a promise that anything which has this in context will be able to access the methods of the type class. (Of course, in your example the method was pretty useless, but even then you could still build other functions on top of it.) Unlike with `CacheableTF`, you can't really use the negation of `CacheableC` at all.
  This aspect is directly reflected in the kinds:

  ```
  CacheableTF :: Type -> Bool
  CacheableC :: Type -> Constraint
  ```
- `CacheableTF` is closed-world, `CacheableC` is open-world. If you want this to be an interface where people can later on make their own types cacheable as well, you need `CacheableC`. But this power is one of the reasons why class constraints can't be negated: just because the compiler can't find any instance while compiling one module, doesn't mean the type won't have an instance by the time the complete program is linked together.

If you want to make a *decision* based on whether or not the type is cacheable, you need `CacheableTF`. However in practice, you'd typically *also* need some methods detailing *how* to cache it, in the `True` case, not just trivial methods like in your `CacheableC`. This can be accomplished by a more general class that covers both the cacheable- and non-cacheable cases:

```
class DecideCache a where
  type IsCacheable a :: Bool
  howToActuallyGoAboutCachingIt
     :: (IsCacheable a ~ 'True) => SomeCompl -> Icated -> Stora -> GeMethod
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that you can also get the open-world behavior by using an open type family instead of a closed type family.